# CSS Anchor look like Button enclosing either image or text

Tags: css, image, button, text, anchor

I have looked over various discussions of the topic of making an HTML anchor tag look like a button but I run into an issue.  My CSS is:

```
a.button:link   { font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #404040;
    border-right: 3px solid #404040;
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 12px 4px 12px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    }
```

If what I enclose in the anchor is an image I have to specify display: inline-block, or the style does not cover the entire rectangle occupied by the image, because anchor by default is an inline tag.  But if I specify inline-block and enclose text within the anchor the text is not aligned properly.  For example see http://www.jamescobban.net/database/CensusForm1901.php?Province=&District=58&SubDistrict=A&Division=1&Page=1.  I would really prefer to be able to use one class for button-like anchors whether the button contains an image or text.

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle of this code.

Comment: And oh gosh that link. Please, for the love of all that is good and pure, read [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/). ;)

Comment: link with image need to be displayed as inline-block , else in some browser the link doesn't entirely wrap its content. You can use vertical-align to move it up or down baseline or center it to text